# How to do a num_rows() on COUNT query in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This works:

```
        $sql = "SELECT id
                FROM `users`
                WHERE `account_status` = '" . $i . "'"; 
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        var_dump($query->num_rows());
```

But this doesn't:

```
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM `users`
                WHERE `account_status` = '" . $i . "'"; 
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        var_dump($query->num_rows());
```

How to do a num_rows on a COUNT(*) query? Also is doing it the 2nd way any better performance wise?

Comment: I should also mention to use the CodeIgniter Active Record class to help organize your code a bit better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doing a `COUNT(*)` will only give you a singular row containing the number of rows and not the results themselves.

To access `COUNT(*)` you would need to do

```
$result = $query->row_array();
$count = $result['COUNT(*)'];
```

The second option performs much better since it does not need to return a dataset to PHP but instead just a count and therefore is much more optimized.

Comment: +1, but it might be worth mentioning that you can alias the column and then use that.  Like `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt ...` and then use `$result['cnt']`.

Comment: @Corbin yea I had to do it like that, COUNT(*) as the key wasn't working for some reason.

Comment: Skip a step and refer directly to the result without setting it as an array first: `COUNT(*) AS cnt ... ` and then access it via `$query->row(0)->cnt`

Comment: @Frug that didn't work for me, but using 'c' alias and $query->row->c did

Answer (score 11):

In CI it's really simple actually, all you need is

```
$this->db->where('account_status', $i);
$num_rows = $this->db->count_all_results('users');
var_dump($num_rows); // prints the number of rows in table users with account status $i
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$query->num_rows()
```

The number of rows returned by the query. Note: In this example, $query is the variable that the query result object is assigned to:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');

echo $query->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 4):

num_rows on your COUNT() query will literally ALWAYS be 1. It is an aggregate function without a GROUP BY clause, so all rows are grouped together into one. If you want the *value* of the count, you should give it an identifier `SELECT COUNT(*) as myCount ...`, then use your normal method of accessing a result (the first, only result) and get it's 'myCount' property.

Answer (score 3):

As per [CI Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results) we can use the following,

```
$this->db->where('account_status', $i); // OTHER CONDITIONS IF ANY
$this->db->from('account_status'); //TABLE NAME
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
```

If we want to get total rows in the table without any condition, simple use

```
echo $this->db->count_all_results('table_name'); // returns total_rows presented in the table
```

Comment: @danneth already offered this advice ~7 years earlier and it shows that the `from()` call is not necessary.

Comment: Kindly read the CI Docs - https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results

Comment: And your point is?  The docs say yoir second snippet should be calling `count_all` instead of `count_all_results()` -- but that is not what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

it's my way of solving the above given question

**model**

```
$this->db->select('count(id) as ids');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->from('your_table_name');
```

thanks

Answer (score -1):

This will only return 1 row, because you're just selecting a `COUNT()`. you will use `mysql_num_rows()` on the `$query` in this case.

If you want to get a count of each of the `ID`'s, add `GROUP BY id` to the end of the string.

Performance-wise, don't ever ever ever use `*` in your queries. If there is 100 unique fields in a table and you want to get them all, you write out all 100, not `*`. This is because `*` has to recalculate how many fields it has to go, every single time it grabs a field, which takes a lot more time to call.

Comment: The OP is specifically looking for a codeigniter technique, not general `mysql_` advice.

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest instead of doing another query with the same parameters just immediately running a `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`

Comment: The OP isn't making two consecutive queries, the OP is offering two techniques to compare (as proof of effort).

Answer (score -2):

```
    $list_data = $this->Estimate_items_model->get_details(array("estimate_id" => $id))->result();
    $result = array();
    $counter = 0;
    $templateProcessor->cloneRow('Title', count($list_data));
    foreach($list_data as $row) {
        $counter++;
        $templateProcessor->setValue('Title#'.$counter, $row->title);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('Description#'.$counter, $row->description);
        $type = $row->unit_type ? $row->unit_type : "";
        $templateProcessor->setValue('Quantity#'.$counter, to_decimal_format($row->quantity) . " " . $type);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('Rate#'.$counter, to_currency($row->rate, $row->currency_symbol));
        $templateProcessor->setValue('Total#'.$counter, to_currency($row->total, $row->currency_symbol));   
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't resemble the posted question in the slightest.  I reckon this code-only post is **Not An Answer** (and unsalvageable).